# Creating an array that comprises all possible combinations of two separate arrays' values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am dealing with coordinates in a grid and I need to make a two dimensional array of all the possible combinations of two input arrays.

Say I have

```
Xcoords = [0, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, etc];
```

and I have

```
Ycoords = [0, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, etc];
```

I want to create a 2D array that contains two value array pairs of every combination in the two dimensional space (a square or rectangular canvas), like:

```
Coords = [[0, 5], [5, 5], [10, 5], etc, etc, etc]
```

The number of items in the 2D array would be [number of items in first array] * [number of items in the second array].

I'm sure I could probably do this with a lot of loops, but what's the most efficient way? I'd really rather not have a dependency like lodash.

Many thanks!

Comment: There is no `5` in the input arrays but it is in the output array. Please fix your question

Comment: Using loops will actually be the most efficient way in terms of performance.